# Why can't I show images inside my slider baguetteBox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, slider

I am designing a slider within my site, for that I am using the baguetteBox library. Looking at the documentation I was able to create an example that works without problem.
I am using php, and I loop through an array to get a list of images

```
<div class="gallery">
   
     '; foreach ($dataFotos['fotos'] as $key) { echo '
       <a href="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-79DdxzZkDog/T76QV6v5IuI/AAAAAAAAAEY/6DzpGZzsmfA/s320/homerocatolico_456_336.jpg">
            <img src="' . $key['foto'] . '" alt="Second image">
      </a>
        '; } echo '
</div>
```

When within this tag I select a url with the following format

`<a href="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-79DdxzZkDog/T76QV6v5IuI/AAAAAAAAAEY/6DzpGZzsmfA/s320/homerocatolico_456_336.jpg">`

Everything works as it should and the slider shows the photos. The problem is that I have the images hosted on drive, and the link that google generates with the following format

`<a href="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/2IYYQLR38oxMnF51zCAGHDeUXlCk69gJBsXogjO-AM-eR-fQwWrnE8XEZt8iSViFBUuDJE5AQQzrS1hX3VPLpU5cSzmuXE07JT9UIJawi0Sp">`

There it stops showing me the images and the slider stops working.

Answer (score 0):

add ?.jpg to the end of url and it worked

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/2IYYQLR38oxMnF51zCAGHDeUXlCk69gJBsXogjO-AM-eR-fQwWrnE8XEZt8iSViFBUuDJE5AQQzrS1hX3VPLpU5cSzmuXE07JT9UIJawi0Sp?.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

- That worked for me

```html
baguetteBox.run('.gallery', {
  filter: /.*/i
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).